# Prevent Chrome from downloading files

Tags: c#, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to display files in a HTML page in an object tag.
I use C# MVC4 to send the file. In my code, I set the "Content-Type" and "Content-Disposition" headers.
When I set the Content-Type to something Chrome dosen't know, it will download the file, regardless of the "Content-Disposition" header.

#### HTML:

```
<div>
<object data="http://localhost/UncHelper?path=secrectPath\file.dwg"></object></div>
```

#### C#:

```
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
    context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", _contentType);
    context.RequestContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + _fileName + "\"");
    context.HttpContext.Response.WriteFile(_uncPath);
    context.HttpContext.Response.End();
}
```

When I try to display a pdf file (_contentType = application/pdf) everything is fine.
But when I try to display a .dwg (_contentType = application/dwg) Chrome will download the file. How can I prevent this?

(I don't want to set a HTML status of 203 based on the browser or anything like that.)

Thanks!

Comment: Well, what would you expect a browser to do with a file it doesn't know how to display? If .dwg files are AutoCad files, I doubt Chrome can make any sense of it. Thus, the most logical operation would be to download the file so it can be opened with the apropriate program.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
FF displays a message stating "no plugin found", that's what I need for Chrome too.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, and is also a slight misunderstanding on your part i think. For a browser to be able to display a file, it first has to be downloaded.. This goes for all file types. For instance, if you were displaying an image of `image/jpeg`, with the disposition set to `inline`, the browser still downloads the image, and then displays it inline, instead of asking the user where he/she would like to save it. If the browser has no knowledge of how to display the file, this is not an option, and will default to the only other option, which is to ask the user where to save it.